# If there is no relative motion between the ground and the bottom of a rotating wheel...is there no friction between the wheel and ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction, free-body-diagram

Also..what happens when the car accelerates.
The bottom of the tire is still at rest relative to ground. So what force pushes the car forward?

Comment: Remember, there are two types of friction: one in the case of relative motion and one in the case without. No relative motion doesn't necessarily mean no friction.

Comment: If the part of the tire touching the ground is *not moving* and the part coming off the ground is going *straight up* and the part coming towards the ground is going *straight down* and the top of the tire is going *twice as fast* as the car, then which direction is the tire 'really' moving? All of the above. Answer: what is a 'cycloid'?

Answer (score 2):

There is static friction between a non-skidding tire and the ground, and it is what allows the car to accelerate, brake, and turn. Similarly, if you stand still on a hill, the reason you don't fall down the hill is static friction between your shoes and the ground. Static friction is the type of friction which can occur when there is no relative motion between two surfaces.

Static friction can provide more force than kinetic or skidding / sliding friction. There is no kinetic friction between the ground and the bottom of a rotating wheel unless the car is skidding, but there is still a force from static friction.

Comment: "when there is no relative moron between two surfaces" -- I'm pretty sure that's not *quite* what you meant to write...

Comment: Its a darn good thing that everything is not made of *scrith*!

Answer (score 0):

When the wheel is rolling without slipping along a horizontal surface the static friction is zero and the wheel continues rolling with no net force or torques acting on it.

If there is an attempt to increase the rotational speed of the wheel and that was unchecked it would result in relative movement between the wheel and the ground at the point of contact.

To prevent that relative movement between the wheel and the ground a static friction force starts to act on the wheel at the point of contact with the ground in a direction which will try and reduce the linear acceleration of the centre of mass of the wheel and produce a torque on the wheel which will try and increase its speed of rotation.
In this case the static frictional force would be in the opposite direction to the direction of motion of the centre of mass of the wheel.

If the static frictional force is not sufficient to maintain the no slipping condition then the kinetic frictional force (which is usually smaller than the static frictional force) will act in the same direction as the static frictional force trying to reduce the relative movement between the wheel and the ground.

Comment: Its a darn good thing that static friction is (usually) greater than dynamic friction. Otherwise, stuff would start to move, then stop again, then start... Wait, that is pretty much what it *is* doing. (Brownian motion and all)